# Is there any way to run .NET Core Published web application via Kestrel in Local Host?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

As I know according to Microsoft Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-5.0#kestrel-in-aspnet-core-apps) in Dotnet core ConfigureWebHostDefaults makes Kestrel default web server inside the project.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

So I can use `Dotnet Run` in my main project path (that contains .sln) and run the project directly with Kestrel without IIS Express and it runs(As I can do that with IIS Express IN VS). But I want to know is there any way to do that in my release production (after Publish) in the local Host in Server? I hosted my project with IIS in server successfully and it works fine but for curiosity, I run `Dotnet run` in my publish root and it returns:

> Welcome to .NET Core 3.1!
> --------------------- SDK Version: 3.1.404
>
> Telemetry
> --------- The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. It is collected by Microsoft and shared with
> the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the
> DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true'
> using your favorite shell.
>
> Read more about .NET Core CLI Tools telemetry:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry
>
> ---------------- Explore documentation: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs Report issues and find source on GitHub:
> https://github.com/dotnet/core Find out what's new:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-whats-new Learn about the installed HTTPS
> developer cert: https://aka.ms/aspnet-core-https Use 'dotnet --help'
> to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs
> Write your first app: https://aka.ms/first-net-core-app

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you've built the project, you can use `dotnet whatever.dll`, the 'run' command is for the source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run

> The dotnet run command is used in the context of projects, not built
> assemblies. If you're trying to run a framework-dependent application
> DLL instead, you must use dotnet without a command. For example, to
> run myapp.dll, use:
>
> `dotnet myapp.dll`

Comment: Yes, I was using without . DLL !! My bad.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how your ASP.NET Core app is published.
Assuming you don't need to target a specific platform, you could first publish a [cross-platform binary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#produce-a-cross-platform-binary) and then use `dotnet` directly on the assembly containing your main program.

As an example, say you have a ASP.NET Core app named MyApp without any specific settings on your `MyApp.csproj` project file.
You can publish it by running `dotnet publish -c Release` from the `MyApp.csproj` file path: the published release will contain your app assemblies, including `MyApp.dll` which contains your main program from where Kestrel is started.
From this location, you can run `dotnet MyApp.dll` to run your ASP.NET Core app.